# Forgotten recovery mode password

Tags: macos, password

I have forgotten the password of recovery mode when I holds command + R. I have no idea how to deal with it so if anyone knows the solution, then let me know.

Comment: [Forgot a Mac Firmware Password? Don’t Panic, Here’s What To Do](http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/28/forgot-mac-firmware-password-what-now/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

- Switch off your Mac (not just log out).
- Boot into Recovery mode by pressing the power button while holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys.
- Select Disk Utility and press Continue.
- Choose Utilities > Terminal.
- Type `resetpassword` (all one word, lowercase letters) and press <kbd>Return</kbd>
- Select the drive containing your user account (this is usually your main drive)
- Choose the account to change with *Select the User Account*
- Enter a new password and re-enter it into the password fields
- Enter a new password hint related to the password
- Click Save. (Note: you may get a warning that the password has changed, but not the Keychain Password. Click OK.)
- Shut down your Mac (Apple > Shut Down)
- Restart your Mac

Comment: I don't think Maze forgot an account password but rather the firmware password!

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Upon re-reading the question, I think you may be right. I'll delete or update my answer once the OP clarifies.